# openstackclient python error during server list

Tags: python, runtime-error, openstack

I have installed openstackclient using following commands but somehow getting strange python error and not able to debug what is wrong here, hope python expert can give me some clue to find out what is wrong.

Install openstackclient on CentOS 7.6 (running python 2.7)

```
yum -y install epel-release
yum install python-pip
pip install python-openstackclient
pip install -U decorator
```

Run openstackclient

```
# source openrc
# openstack server list --debug
    START with options: server list --debug
    options: Namespace(access_token='***', access_token_endpoint='', access_token_type='', application_credential_id='', application_credential_name='', application_credential_secret='***', auth_methods='', auth_type='password', auth_url='http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3', cacert=None, cert='', client_id='', client_secret='***', cloud='', code='', debug=True, default_domain='default', default_domain_id='', default_domain_name='', deferred_help=False, discovery_endpoint='', domain_id='', domain_name='', endpoint='', identity_provider='', identity_provider_url='', insecure=None, interface='internalURL', key='', log_file=None, openid_scope='', os_beta_command=False, os_compute_api_version='', os_identity_api_version='3', os_image_api_version='', os_network_api_version='', os_object_api_version='', os_orchestration_api_version='1', os_project_id=None, os_project_name=None, os_volume_api_version='', passcode='', password='***', project_domain_id='', project_domain_name='Default', project_id='', project_name='admin', protocol='', redirect_uri='', region_name='RegionOne', remote_project_domain_id='', remote_project_domain_name='', remote_project_id='', remote_project_name='', service_provider='', service_provider_endpoint='', service_provider_entity_id='', system_scope='', timing=False, token='***', trust_id='', url='', user_domain_id='', user_domain_name='Default', user_id='', username='admin', verbose_level=3, verify=None)
    Auth plugin password selected
    auth_config_hook(): {'auth_type': 'password', 'beta_command': False, u'image_status_code_retries': '5', 'orchestration_api_version': '1', 'timing': False, 'auth_url': 'http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3', u'network_api_version': u'2', u'message': u'', u'image_format': u'qcow2', 'networks': [], 'verify': True, u'object_store_api_version': u'1', u'status': u'active', 'verbose_level': 3, 'region_name': 'RegionOne', u'baremetal_introspection_status_code_retries': '5', 'api_timeout': None, 'auth': {'user_domain_name': 'Default', 'project_name': 'admin', 'project_domain_name': 'Default'}, 'default_domain': 'default', u'image_api_use_tasks': False, u'floating_ip_source': u'neutron', 'key': None, 'cacert': None, 'password': '***', u'baremetal_status_code_retries': '5', 'identity_api_version': '3', 'username': 'admin', 'deferred_help': False, 'cert': None, u'secgroup_source': u'neutron', 'debug': True, u'interface': 'internalURL', u'disable_vendor_agent': {}}
    defaults: {u'auth_type': 'password', u'status': u'active', u'image_status_code_retries': 5, u'baremetal_introspection_status_code_retries': 5, 'api_timeout': None, 'cacert': None, u'image_api_use_tasks': False, u'floating_ip_source': u'neutron', 'key': None, u'interface': None, u'network_api_version': u'2', u'message': u'', u'image_format': u'qcow2', u'baremetal_status_code_retries': 5, 'verify': True, 'cert': None, u'secgroup_source': u'neutron', u'object_store_api_version': u'1', u'disable_vendor_agent': {}}
    cloud cfg: {'auth_type': 'password', 'beta_command': False, u'image_status_code_retries': '5', 'orchestration_api_version': '1', 'cacert': None, 'auth_url': 'http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3', u'network_api_version': u'2', u'message': u'', u'image_format': u'qcow2', 'networks': [], 'verify': True, u'object_store_api_version': u'1', u'status': u'active', 'verbose_level': 3, 'region_name': 'RegionOne', u'baremetal_introspection_status_code_retries': '5', 'api_timeout': None, 'auth': {'user_domain_name': 'Default', 'project_name': 'admin', 'project_domain_name': 'Default'}, 'default_domain': 'default', u'image_api_use_tasks': False, u'floating_ip_source': u'neutron', 'key': None, 'timing': False, 'password': '***', u'baremetal_status_code_retries': '5', 'identity_api_version': '3', 'username': 'admin', 'deferred_help': False, 'cert': None, u'secgroup_source': u'neutron', 'debug': True, u'interface': 'internalURL', u'disable_vendor_agent': {}}
    compute API version 2.1, cmd group openstack.compute.v2
    network API version 2, cmd group openstack.network.v2
    image API version 2, cmd group openstack.image.v2
    volume API version 2, cmd group openstack.volume.v2
    identity API version 3, cmd group openstack.identity.v3
    object_store API version 1, cmd group openstack.object_store.v1
    orchestration API version 1, cmd group openstack.orchestration.v1
    Auth plugin password selected
    auth_config_hook(): {'auth_type': 'password', 'beta_command': False, u'image_status_code_retries': '5', 'orchestration_api_version': '1', 'timing': False, 'auth_url': 'http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3', u'network_api_version': u'2', u'message': u'', u'image_format': u'qcow2', 'networks': [], 'verify': True, u'object_store_api_version': u'1', u'status': u'active', 'verbose_level': 3, 'region_name': 'RegionOne', u'baremetal_introspection_status_code_retries': '5', 'api_timeout': None, 'auth': {'user_domain_name': 'Default', 'project_name': 'admin', 'project_domain_name': 'Default'}, 'default_domain': 'default', u'image_api_use_tasks': False, u'floating_ip_source': u'neutron', 'key': None, 'cacert': None, 'password': '***', u'baremetal_status_code_retries': '5', 'identity_api_version': '3', 'username': 'admin', 'deferred_help': False, 'cert': None, u'secgroup_source': u'neutron', 'debug': True, u'interface': 'internalURL', u'disable_vendor_agent': {}}
    Auth plugin password selected
    auth_config_hook(): {'auth_type': 'password', 'beta_command': False, u'image_status_code_retries': '5', 'orchestration_api_version': '1', 'timing': False, 'auth_url': 'http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3', u'network_api_version': u'2', u'message': u'', u'image_format': u'qcow2', 'networks': [], 'verify': True, u'object_store_api_version': u'1', u'status': u'active', 'verbose_level': 3, 'region_name': 'RegionOne', u'baremetal_introspection_status_code_retries': '5', 'api_timeout': None, 'auth': {'user_domain_name': 'Default', 'project_name': 'admin', 'project_domain_name': 'Default'}, 'default_domain': 'default', u'image_api_use_tasks': False, u'floating_ip_source': u'neutron', 'key': None, 'cacert': None, 'password': '***', u'baremetal_status_code_retries': '5', 'identity_api_version': '3', 'username': 'admin', 'deferred_help': False, 'cert': None, u'secgroup_source': u'neutron', 'debug': True, u'interface': 'internalURL', u'disable_vendor_agent': {}}
    command: server list -> openstackclient.compute.v2.server.ListServer (auth=True)
    Auth plugin password selected
    auth_config_hook(): {'auth_type': 'password', 'beta_command': False, u'image_status_code_retries': '5', 'key': None, 'timing': False, 'auth_url': 'http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3', 'additional_user_agent': [('osc-lib', '1.14.1')], u'network_api_version': u'2', u'message': u'', u'image_format': u'qcow2', 'networks': [], 'verify': True, u'object_store_api_version': u'1', u'status': u'active', 'verbose_level': 3, 'region_name': 'RegionOne', u'baremetal_introspection_status_code_retries': '5', 'api_timeout': None, 'auth': {'user_domain_name': 'Default', 'project_name': 'admin', 'project_domain_name': 'Default'}, 'default_domain': 'default', u'image_api_use_tasks': False, u'floating_ip_source': u'neutron', 'orchestration_api_version': '1', u'interface': 'internalURL', 'password': '***', 'cacert': None, u'baremetal_status_code_retries': '5', 'identity_api_version': '3', 'username': 'admin', 'deferred_help': False, 'cert': None, u'secgroup_source': u'neutron', 'debug': True, u'disable_vendor_agent': {}}
    Using auth plugin: password
    Using parameters {'username': 'admin', 'project_name': 'admin', 'user_domain_name': 'Default', 'auth_url': 'http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3', 'password': '***', 'project_domain_name': 'Default'}
    Get auth_ref
    REQ: curl -g -i -X GET http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: openstacksdk/0.37.0 keystoneauth1/3.18.0 python-requests/2.22.0 CPython/2.7.5"
    Starting new HTTP connection (1): 172.28.16.9:5000
    http://172.28.16.9:5000 "GET /v3 HTTP/1.1" 200 251
    RESP: [200] Connection: close Content-Length: 251 Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https: wss:; Content-Type: application/json Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2019 03:44:52 GMT Server: nginx/1.16.1 Vary: X-Auth-Token X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: DENY X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block x-openstack-request-id: req-490ab2ff-c0b9-4436-bf8d-0771f3ac5ffe
    RESP BODY: {"version": {"status": "stable", "updated": "2019-01-22T00:00:00Z", "media-types": [{"base": "application/json", "type": "application/vnd.openstack.identity-v3+json"}], "id": "v3.12", "links": [{"href": "http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3/", "rel": "self"}]}}
    GET call to http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3 used request id req-490ab2ff-c0b9-4436-bf8d-0771f3ac5ffe
    Making authentication request to http://172.28.16.9:5000/v3/auth/tokens
    Resetting dropped connection: 172.28.16.9
    http://172.28.16.9:5000 "POST /v3/auth/tokens HTTP/1.1" 201 4640
    {"token": {"is_domain": false, "methods": ["password"], "roles": [{"id": "9944533d28d64d1ca7c5f8c580896020", "name": "admin"}, {"id": "4633f54340d2453e8b186326eed8aef5", "name": "member"}, {"id": "05e2dc8cbfad49838cbfa683e7eb7325", "name": "reader"}], "expires_at": "2019-11-26T15:44:52.000000Z", "project": {"domain": {"id": "default", "name": "Default"}, "id": "17e53f35988a4b4a9a32c8cfeec05537", "name": "admin"}, "catalog": [{"endpoints": [{"url": "http://172.28.16.9:8780", "interface": "internal", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "0ca74408bb074d24b22dd2aa00eff820"}, {"url": "https://10.30.16.9:8780", "interface": "public", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "27924cb00b53432e8beb34b056e67ff1"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:8780", "interface": "admin", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "79b09d9892bf4f3cbdcf2784a1684c2f"}], "type": "placement", "id": "1c74655d5e1e4191b959e96cabcfefbd", "name": "placement"}, {"endpoints": [{"url": "https://10.30.16.9:8774/v2.1", "interface": "public", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "27ffcc6bb7d944c1a6c04e91c830efc3"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:8774/v2.1", "interface": "internal", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "7b128ef8a8be4173b38121ed20d87e52"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:8774/v2.1", "interface": "admin", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "c6f91cda858344f9b6cc515f1e3a99a8"}], "type": "compute", "id": "26d2b7fb2a1440298aa9547445c26496", "name": "nova"}, {"endpoints": [{"url": "https://10.30.16.9:8000/v1", "interface": "public", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "4441551e12fc47f3bcf16a2fc35bd7e0"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:8000/v1", "interface": "admin", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "6cb8f78140214c71953ad20befeb9c0a"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:8000/v1", "interface": "internal", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "771f3bfada8a4a2c8f61f853377bfe73"}], "type": "cloudformation", "id": "3fc58bddeddb4cd3bda8445ee31c84cd", "name": "heat-cfn"}, {"endpoints": [{"url": "https://10.30.16.9:9696", "interface": "public", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "0eefb65249f84092b41cd70c59f8598e"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:9696", "interface": "internal", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "56fa92d9b7104f27b17382479860f2d5"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:9696", "interface": "admin", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "bf99e2da368d4367ab76a16c682e9aa2"}], "type": "network", "id": "6c04b2fa2e444ebd8e4c13ce7e2c324a", "name": "neutron"}, {"endpoints": [{"url": "https://10.30.16.9:8004/v1/17e53f35988a4b4a9a32c8cfeec05537", "interface": "public", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "7dd979b3ea6d4459a780aa09baff8d06"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:8004/v1/17e53f35988a4b4a9a32c8cfeec05537", "interface": "internal", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "87c6d36c25774c958daaab11ef2a51a3"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:8004/v1/17e53f35988a4b4a9a32c8cfeec05537", "interface": "admin", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "fc62f32a3ee4463eaa09d7bbb00e1b90"}], "type": "orchestration", "id": "952ae979ecb7472f83010be177ddb282", "name": "heat"}, {"endpoints": [{"url": "https://10.30.16.9:9292", "interface": "public", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "5fd1c9cc608e4134b0ddd5a230401c6f"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:9292", "interface": "admin", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "a95c4a55f1c84ac9aee4b85874fa3893"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:9292", "interface": "internal", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "ff2819e67b8c4ff1b650d6c2af4b551c"}], "type": "image", "id": "988a3140f151414a9ecde2cd4211a4ab", "name": "glance"}, {"endpoints": [{"url": "http://172.28.16.9:5000", "interface": "admin", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "3ff947111a994736b327155d6671dde9"}, {"url": "http://172.28.16.9:5000", "interface": "internal", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "7b69d078595e4ce1bc94c1ec3b63ecf4"}, {"url": "https://10.30.16.9:5000", "interface": "public", "region": "RegionOne", "region_id": "RegionOne", "id": "f333086d636d4db29a490c90fa1a4737"}], "type": "identity", "id": "b2afa2ef07cb4d8fa9c1391221d7c8d8", "name": "keystone"}], "user": {"domain": {"id": "default", "name": "Default"}, "password_expires_at": null, "name": "admin", "id": "093c1e3cb4964d3c9b842c671689e2b1"}, "audit_ids": ["DbzIEG-oQgq-f8WX9GAI4g"], "issued_at": "2019-11-26T03:44:52.000000Z"}}
    run(Namespace(all_projects=False, changes_before=None, changes_since=None, columns=[], deleted=False, fit_width=False, flavor=None, formatter='table', host=None, image=None, instance_name=None, ip=None, ip6=None, limit=None, long=False, marker=None, max_width=0, name=None, name_lookup_one_by_one=False, no_name_lookup=False, noindent=False, print_empty=False, project=None, project_domain=None, quote_mode='nonnumeric', reservation_id=None, sort_columns=[], status=None, user=None, user_domain=None))
    Instantiating compute client for API Version Major: 2, Minor: 1
    Instantiating compute api: <class 'openstackclient.api.compute_v2.APIv2'>
    Instantiating identity client: <class 'keystoneclient.v3.client.Client'>
    invalid syntax (more.py, line 340)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cliff/app.py", line 401, in run_subcommand
        result = cmd.run(parsed_args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osc_lib/command/command.py", line 41, in run
        return super(Command, self).run(parsed_args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cliff/display.py", line 116, in run
        column_names, data = self.take_action(parsed_args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstackclient/compute/v2/server.py", line 1168, in take_action
        image_client = self.app.client_manager.image
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osc_lib/clientmanager.py", line 47, in __get__
        self._handle = self.factory(instance)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstackclient/image/client.py", line 45, in make_client
        API_VERSIONS)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osc_lib/utils/__init__.py", line 428, in get_client_class
        return importutils.import_class(client_path)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/importutils.py", line 30, in import_class
        __import__(mod_str)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glanceclient/v2/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
        from glanceclient.v2.client import Client      # noqa
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glanceclient/v2/client.py", line 19, in <module>
        from glanceclient.v2 import image_members
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glanceclient/v2/image_members.py", line 16, in <module>
        import warlock
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/warlock/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from warlock.core import model_factory  # NOQA
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/warlock/core.py", line 19, in <module>
        from . import model
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/warlock/model.py", line 21, in <module>
        import jsonschema
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
        import importlib_metadata
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
        import zipp
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zipp.py", line 12, in <module>
        import more_itertools
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/more_itertools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from more_itertools.more import *  # noqa
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/more_itertools/more.py", line 340
        def _collate(*iterables, key=lambda a: a, reverse=False):
                                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    clean_up ListServer: invalid syntax (more.py, line 340)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osc_lib/shell.py", line 136, in run
        ret_val = super(OpenStackShell, self).run(argv)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cliff/app.py", line 281, in run
        result = self.run_subcommand(remainder)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osc_lib/shell.py", line 176, in run_subcommand
        ret_value = super(OpenStackShell, self).run_subcommand(argv)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cliff/app.py", line 401, in run_subcommand
        result = cmd.run(parsed_args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osc_lib/command/command.py", line 41, in run
        return super(Command, self).run(parsed_args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cliff/display.py", line 116, in run
        column_names, data = self.take_action(parsed_args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstackclient/compute/v2/server.py", line 1168, in take_action
        image_client = self.app.client_manager.image
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osc_lib/clientmanager.py", line 47, in __get__
        self._handle = self.factory(instance)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstackclient/image/client.py", line 45, in make_client
        API_VERSIONS)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osc_lib/utils/__init__.py", line 428, in get_client_class
        return importutils.import_class(client_path)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/importutils.py", line 30, in import_class
        __import__(mod_str)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glanceclient/v2/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
        from glanceclient.v2.client import Client      # noqa
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glanceclient/v2/client.py", line 19, in <module>
        from glanceclient.v2 import image_members
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glanceclient/v2/image_members.py", line 16, in <module>
        import warlock
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/warlock/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from warlock.core import model_factory  # NOQA
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/warlock/core.py", line 19, in <module>
        from . import model
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/warlock/model.py", line 21, in <module>
        import jsonschema
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
        import importlib_metadata
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
        import zipp
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zipp.py", line 12, in <module>
        import more_itertools
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/more_itertools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from more_itertools.more import *  # noqa
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/more_itertools/more.py", line 340
        def _collate(*iterables, key=lambda a: a, reverse=False):
                                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    END return value: 1
```

Comment: The problem is probably in your keystone.conf

Comment: Keystone has nothing to do with this error message.

Comment: Yes.. my keystone working fine only problem is `openstack server list` throwing error , if i run `openstack user list` it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indicated line...

```
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/more_itertools/more.py", line 340
        def _collate(*iterables, key=lambda a: a, reverse=False):
                                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

...is using syntax that only works with Python 3.x. Your system has Python 2.7. Assuming that you are using the correct version of EPEL, this looks like a packaging bug.

**EDIT**

I missed the fact that you were `pip installing` things, rather than relying on your package manager. First, don't do that: running `pip install` into the system Python libraries is going to break things at some point. If you're going to use `pip`, then install things into a virtual environment where it won't conflict with system tooling.

If you were installing things into a virtual environment, you could simply remove and re-create the virtual environment. I worry that you are going to discover other problems even if we are able to solve the `more-itertools` issue.

Given that `more_itertools` appears to be used by some of the code, I suspect that simply removing it will break things. You may be able to explicitly install an earlier, python 2.x compatible version of it. Try running:

```
pip install more-itertools==5.0.0
```

Comment: system had python3 install earlier which i have uninstall and now it has no trace of any python3 or pip3. I have uninstall openstackclient and re-install it but still getting error. One thing i found which is `more_itertools` module isn't install on other servers and they are working fine with openstackclient, only this machine throwing this error look like `more_itertools` doing some stuff which openstackclient doesn't like, how do i remove `more_itertools`?

Comment: What is the output of `pip list installed | grep more-itertools` on your system?  Running `pip install python-openstackenv` on my centos7 system got me `more-itertools` version `5.0.0`, which has definition of `_collate` that is Python 2 compatible.

Comment: it saying `more-itertools (7.2.0)`

Comment: Try running `pip install more-itertools==5.0.0`.

Comment: Damnn!!! i was going to tell you that `pip install more-itertools==5.0.0` fixed my issue :) Thank you so much for help...